# Using Haxe, how can I generate python code with type hints?

Tags: python, python-3.x, haxe

I want to write a cross-platform library with Haxe. But when I compile Haxe to Python, there is no type hint in Python code.

How to let Haxe generate type hints to Python code? This helps users use my library more conveniently.

Although I have placed type hints in the haxe code, my python code after being generated does not have them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.